# Добавление сборки в GAC

Tags: c#, assembly, gac

Несколько вопросов по теме. При добавлении сборки в GAC, происходит ли копирование сборки в Windows\assembly? Если происходит, то как ее потом найти? Через командную строку сборка добавляется, но в папке assembly она не появляется. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в Visual Studio при добавлении ссылки показывается список сборок в GAC? Если это так, то почему я не вижу там своей сборки?
Добавлял так: gacutil /i mydll.dll
Пишет: сборка успешно добавлена в кэш

Comment: Нет, не все сборки из GAC показываются в списке Visual Studio: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1987697/276994

Comment: Кстати, ответом ниже есть ссылочка на extension, который позволяет добавлять в проект ссылки на сборки прямо из GAC'а: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2736187/1260215

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Внутренняя структура каталогов GAC:

   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\

   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\

   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_64\

   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\

   само собой, это для 64битных машин. смысл вопроса я не очень понял.
2. либо `gacutil -l`, либо просмотром в файл-менеджерах.
3. [здесь](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306149) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987691/assembly-installed-into-the-gac-not-showing-up-in-visual-studio)

Comment: GAC один. В первом пункте вы лишь указали его внутреннюю структуру каталогов.

Comment: @Shad, да, Вы правы, неверная формулировка, это к вопросу ТС про \windows\assembly\.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и комментарии. Стало понятно куда копать дальше.

Answer (score 0):

Сборки, управляемые .NET 4.0 и выше находятся по адресу C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL